# How would I use Reddis + Azure Event Hubs to handle mobile push notifications archiving for billions of topics?

Tags: redis, apple-push-notifications, apache-kafka, azure-notificationhub, azure-eventhub

I need to design a system that allows

- Users to subscribe to any topic
- No defined topic limit
- Control over sending to one device, or all
- Recovery when offline clients, (or APNS) that drops a notification. Provide a way to catch up via REST
- Discard all updates older than age T.

I studied many different solutions, such as Notification Hubs, Service Bus, Event Hub... and now discovered Kafka and not sure if that's a good fit.

**Draft architecture**

1. Use an [Event Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-hubs/) to listen for mobile deviceID registrations, and userIDs that requests for topic subscriptions .. Pass that to Reddis, below
2. - If registering a phone/subscribing to a topic, save the deviceID userID to the topic key.
   - If sending a message to a topic, query Reddis for the topic key, and send that result to a FIFO queue for processing.
     Pipe the output of the previous query into the built in Reddis Pub/Sub features to alert worker roles that there is work pending.
3. While the workers send notices to Apple and Firebase, archive out the sent notices to some in-memory store below.
4. Archive server maintains a history of sent events, so that out-of-sync devices can get the most up to date information LIFO-queue style.

**Question**

What are your thoughts on using this approach to solve the above needs?

What other things should I learn, research, or experiment (measure)?

Comment: What does "No defined topic limit" mean? Are you talking about topic names, or just the maximum number of unique topics?

Comment: @HansJespersen Azure Notification hubs and Service bus both claim to support unlimited topics (as mentioned in a few MSFT videos). I suspect I can model my solution after this.

Comment: Kafka does not support unlimited number of topics but it does support an unlimited number of keys so for IOT or mobile use cases you typically use AMQP or MQTT and then map those topics into Kafka keys on a consolidated Kafka topic